# Subscribing to "beforeChange" on dependentObservable creates unwanted dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, knockout.js

When using subscribe with "beforeChange" on a dependentObservable it will create dependencies to any observable accesed within the callback as the event occurs during dependency detection.

For example, comparing the current value against the previous value in a handler will cause an infinite recursion because it will be dependent on itself.

Is there anyway around this?  Is this expected? It seems counter intuitive.  Looking at the code it seems the event could easily be triggered outside of dependency detection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue logged on Github for this one already: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/341

Hopefully, we can get it addressed soon.

For now, you could choose to execute your subscription code in a `setTimeout(function() { //your code here }, 0)`, which would run as soon as the current execution finishes, which may or may not work for your scenario.